# Can I dynamically derive Dax Filters from "dissecting"a criteria field in my database?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a database table that contains records, where each record has a criteria attribute. This criteria attribute can hold anywhere between 1-n criteria that I'd like to apply as filters on a different table.

This looks something like:

`message.status:::eq:::submitted;;;message.count:::ge:::5`

but could also be only

`message.count:::ge:::5`

What I'd like to do in DAX, is take that string and translate it into dynamic Filter attributes. So I somehow need to split the string based on `;;;`, and then disect each section into the target (e.g. message[count]), the operator (e.g. ge --> >=) and the value (e.g. 5).

So in the end the following DAX snippet should be added to my Calculate 1 or more times:

```
example measure = CALCULATE(
   COUNTROWS('message),
    FILTER (
        ALL('message'),
        --- line below should be dynamically injected
        message[count] >= 5
    ),
```

I'm struggling with how to create a loop (is this even possible in PBI?), and then even with a single string... hoe to filter based on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try to build new table for splited message.

```
Table 2 = 

var _splitby = ";;;"
var _string =  SELECTCOLUMNS(ADDCOLUMNS(VALUES('Table'[message]),"pathx", SUBSTITUTE([message],_splitby,"|")),"pathx",[pathx])
var _generate =  GENERATE(_string, GENERATESERIES(1, PATHLENGTH([pathx])))
var _GetVal =  SELECTCOLUMNS(_generate,  "Msg", PATHITEM([pathx], [Value]))

return
_GetVal
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, look good. Only thing I'm still wondering is then how to deal with the use case that there can be muliple criteria?

Answer (score 0):

If you have always **message.count:::ge:::** like string at the end, you can follow these steps in **Power Query**-

Step 1: Duplicate you **message** column

Step-2: apply split on new duplicated column using string **message.count:::ge:::** and you will have a new column with last **Numeric** value from your original text.

Step-3: you can now apply filter on the new column.

Sample Output-

[image]